# Series expansion in a recurrence relation (Lines in a plane)

Tags: proof-explanation, recurrence-relations

L

The recurrence is therefore

L<sub>0</sub> = 1 ;

L<sub>n</sub> = L<sub>n−1</sub> + n , for n > 0.

The known values of L<sub>1</sub> , L<sub>2</sub> , and L<sub>3</sub> check perfectly here, so we'll buy this.
Now we need a closed-form solution. We could play the guessing game
again, but 1 , 2 , 4 , 7 , 11 , 16 , . . . doesn't look familiar; so let's try another
tack. We can often understand a recurrence by "unfolding" or "unwinding"
it all the way to the end, as follows:

L<sub>n</sub> = L<sub>n-1</sub> + n

= L<sub>n−2</sub> + (n − 1) + n

= L<sub>n−3</sub> + (n − 2) + (n − 1) + n

.

.

= L<sub>0</sub> + 1 + 2 + · · · + (n − 2) + (n − 1) + n

= 1 + S<sub>n</sub> , where S n = 1 + 2 + 3 + · · · + (n − 1) + n.

In other words, L n is one more than the sum S n of the first n positive integers.

I didn't understand how

= L<sub>0</sub> + 1 + 2 + · · · + (n − 2) + (n − 1) + n is derived from previous step

Comment: Just compute the first terms using the recurrence relation and try to detect the pattern.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I tried to do that. L0 = 1, L1 = 2 and L2 = 4 and so on. But how did the series contain 1 + 2 + 3 +...(how did 3 came into picture?)